issues with installing Ubuntu LTS on USB drive
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my USB 32 GB using erase the disk and install Ubuntu and did not install any updates or third party drivers during installation. My purpose is to use this USB as portable Ubuntu OS. But this USB is not recognise on any PC as bootable device.
I would appreciate some help and guidance.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it). Or just use 24.04, it will install the bootloaders where you tell it. BUT, a full install gets the necessary drivers for that machine -- machines with different hardware may not work. The persistent install medium using the "try" option is more portable.

Does this answer your question? Installing Ubuntu in a external hard drive and NOT placing GRUB of my C: hard drive

To add to what @ubfan1 said, WiFi, and graphics (video) cards  often need special drivers. These may not work when you boot a different PC from your USB drive. See What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive? for more.
